# How to implement history plugin for prototypejs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, hashcode, history.js

I am using AJAX with **prototypejs**. Now I want to use browser's back/forward button to redirect to already visited AJAX links. I found [this plugin](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) but I don't know which file I have to include in my project and from where to start. I am using following prototypejs code for AJAX requests with JSON response.

```
function ajaxRequest(url) {

parent.location.hash = url;

new Ajax.Request( url, {

      method: 'get',
      onSuccess: function( transport ) {

        // get json response
        var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON( true );

        for(var id in json) {
            $(id).innerHTML = json[id];
        }
    },     
    onFailure: function() {         
        alert('Error with AJAX request.'); 
    }  
});

return false;
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/). You route your ajax calls through a hidden iframe that in-turn calls them from the parent page. When the user presses BACK it makes the iframe go back, therefore executing the prior ajax call.

Comment: Yup, Prototype is even older than that.